# type mismatch cannot convert from element type object to string

Tags: java, string, object, mismatch

I keep getting this error when making a search method in my code to search through string. I have gone through alot of examples trying to fix this but I cant find any. Thank you for any help and advise you can give.

```
public class runNote {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Notebook note = new Notebook();
    note.storeNote("happy");
    note.storeNote("hello there");
    note.storeNote("work at 5");
    note.storeNote("BBQ Time");
    note.storeNote("UNI!!!!");
    note.storeNote("Dont miss lecture at 9:15");
    System.out.println(note.numberOfNotes());
    note.showNote(1);
    note.searchNotes("hap");

}}




public class Notebook{


/**
 * Perform any initialization that is required for the
 * notebook.
 */
public Notebook()
{
    notes = new ArrayList();
}

/**
 * Store a new note into the notebook.
 * @param note The note to be stored.
 */
public void storeNote(String note)
{
    notes.add(note);
}

/**
 * @return The number of notes currently in the notebook.
 */
public int numberOfNotes()
{
    return notes.size();
}

/**
 * A simple search engine to find the correct notes.
 */
public void searchNotes(String search){ 
    for (String item : notes){
        if (item.contains(search)){
        System.out.println(item);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Show a note.
 * @param noteNumber The number of the note to be shown.
 */
public void showNote(int noteNumber)
{
    if(noteNumber < 0) {
        // This is not a valid note number, so do nothing.
    }
    else if(noteNumber < numberOfNotes()) {
        // This is a valid note number, so we can print it.
        System.out.println(notes.get(noteNumber));
    }
    else {
        // This is not a valid note number, so do nothing.
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Paste the exact and complete error message, and tell us which line it refers to.

Comment: Where is the declaration for `notes`? Are you declaring it as `ArrayList` when you should declare it as `ArrayList<String>`?

Comment: Error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to String

 at lab8.Notebook.searchNotes(Notebook.java:47)
 at lab8.runNote.main(runNote.java:16)

Comment: The declaration for notes is in the public Notebook()
{
    notes = new ArrayList();
}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add notes as a global variable to your class

```
public class Notebook{
ArrayList<String> notes = null;

....
}
```

In the constructor, do:

```
public Notebook()
{
    notes = new ArrayList<String>();
}
```

Comment: This is a *member* variable, not a *global* one.

Comment: That is a default constructor

Comment: In Java 7, you don't need to specify String type with the new

Comment: @Code-Guru, thank you, in fact *complete different exception* :) ;)

Answer (score 5):

You are having exception at this line :

```
 for (String item : notes)
```

`notes` is an `ArrayList` declared as raw type, although i don't see the declaration i can see this line of initialization:

```
notes = new ArrayList();
```

which sees it's element as of type `Object` You need to declare `notes`  with `ArrayList<String>` type such as:

```
  ArrayList<String> notes = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: If I change the declaration I get this error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at lab8.Notebook.storeNote(Notebook.java:32)
 at lab8.runNote.main(runNote.java:8)

Comment: have you initialized `notes` list as i described above ?

Answer (score 0):

try this: `notes = new ArrayList<String>();`

Answer (score 0):

You don't declare the notes variable

```
public class Notebook{
  private ArrayList<String> notes;
...
```