# Is org.json.simple.JSONArray poorly designed?

Tags: java, json, generics

I know from https://stackoverflow.com/a/20445493/2848676 that the following code gives the error `type mismatch cannot convert from element type object to string`:

```
ArrayList objectArray = new ArrayList();
for (String str : objectArray) {
```

The compiler is giving me a warning in my declaration of objectArray that says `ArrayList is a raw type. References to generic type ArrayList<E> should be parameterized`.  This all makes perfect sense to me.  The fix is to specify the generic types:

```
ArrayList<String> stringArray = new ArrayList<String>();
for (String str : stringArray) {
```

This avoids the compiler warning and the compilation error.

My problem though is I'm trying to iterate over a subclass of ArrayList called `org.json.simple.JSONArray` and I don't have control over how the JSONArray is instantiated.  Consequently I don't see the compiler warning anywhere but I do get the compilation error in this `for` loop line of code:

```
JSONArray insights = (JSONArray)jsonResult.get("insights");
for (JSONObject insightGroup : insights) {
```

I know I can work around this like this:

```
JSONArray insights = (JSONArray)jsonResult.get("insights");
for (int i=0; i<insights.size(); i++) {
    JSONObject insightGroup = (JSONObject) insights.get(i);
```

But can someone explain the finer points of generic types?  In particular, how can the `org.json.simple.JSONArray` be instantiated without specifying the generic types?  Is `org.json.simple.JSONArray` just poorly designed?  Or am I not using the `org.json.simple.JSONArray` correctly?

Comment: Imagine that you want to use JSON with a legacy application that is running under java 1.4.  Now, try to resolve generics with java 1.4.  Backwards compatibility is a potential reason; I don't know if it is the reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is org.json.simple.JSONArray just poorly designed?

In my opinion, yes, but not for the reason you've described.

A JSON array can contain any JSON value type, not just JSON objects. So

```
for (JSONObject insightGroup : insights) {
```

should not be allowed, and isn't. The `JSONObject` type represents a JSON object. But the `JSONArray` can contain `String` values, other `JSONArray` values, numerical values, `null`, or other `JSONObject` values.

The JSON format is described [here](http://json.org/).

Maybe that is the reason that `JSONArray` was implemented as extending and implementing raw `List` types, [which is typically not a good idea.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)

Comment: I think I just found how JSON Simple (i.e. org.json.simple) was intended to be used.  There is a (`ContainerFactory`)[https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/DecodingExamples#Example_4_-_Container_factory] that allows you to specify classes in the (Java Collections Framework)[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/collections/index.html].  And, "If you don't specify a container factory, org.json.simple.JSONObject is used for a Map and org.json.simple.JSONArray is used for a List."

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, looks like JSONArray is an `ArrayList<Object>` under the covers.  Try creating an `ArrayList<JSONObject>`, something like this:

```
// The json-simple way
ArrayList<JSONObject> jsonThings = (JSONArray)JSONValue.parse(jsonString);
for (JSONObject j : jsonThings) {
    System.out.println("This is it:  " + j.toJSONString());
}
```

Or cast all over the place like this:

```
for (Object j : jsonThings) { 
    System.out.println("This is it:  " + ((JSONObject)j).toJSONString());
}
```