# Foreach with JSONArray and JSONObject

Tags: java, json

I'm using `org.json.simple.JSONArray` and `org.json.simple.JSONObject`. I know that these two classes `JSONArray` and `JSONObject` are incompatible, but still I want to do quite a natural thing - I want to for-each over `JSONArray` parsing at each iteration step one `JSONObject` (nested inside that `JSONArray`). I try to do it like so:

```
JSONArray arr = ...; // <-- got by some procedure
for(JSONObject o: arr){
    parse(o);
}
```

When I try to compile this code, indeed I get "incompatible types" error, even though it looks so natural. So, my question is what is the best way to iterate through `JSONArray`?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Apparently, `org.json.simple.JSONArray` implements a *raw* Iterator. This means that each element is considered to be an `Object`. You can try to cast:

```
for(Object o: arr){
    if ( o instanceof JSONObject ) {
        parse((JSONObject)o);
    }
}
```

This is how things were done back in Java 1.4 and earlier.

Comment: Thanks! It works. Though, it seems like I did it using `java.util.Iterator`

Comment: @Jacobian Yes, it's `java.util.Iterator`, but it's a *raw* one (E.g. a `List<String>` would return an `Iterator<String>`, and then you can use `String` as the enhanced for loop variable's type. When it's raw, the base type is assumed to be `Object`.

Answer (score 73):

Seems like you can't iterate through `JSONArray` with a `for each`. You can loop through your `JSONArray` like this:

```
for (int i=0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
    arr.getJSONObject(i);
}
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4784874/is-it-possible-to-iterate-through-jsonarray)

Comment: Thanks! Will check it in a second.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, it seems like `JSONArray` from `org.json.simple.*` does not have `length()` method and `getJSONObject()`

Comment: @Jacobian Have you tried using `org.json.JSONArray`?

Comment: Now, I have not tried it, yet. Is it much more powerful?

Comment: @Jacobian I've never used `org.json.simple.JSONArray` so I can't say. Maybe @RealSkeptic has better knowledge about that :)

Comment: @Jacobian [I found this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26936436/is-org-json-simple-jsonarray-poorly-designed)

Comment: For `org.json.simple.JSONArray` you need to use the `size()` method (instead of `length()`) inherited from java.util.ArrayList.

Answer (score 39):

Make sure you are using this org.json:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json

if you are using Java 8 then you can use

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

JSONArray array = ...;

array.forEach(item -> {
    JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) item;
    parse(obj);
});
```

**Just added a simple test to prove that it works:**

Add the following dependency into your `pom.xml` file (To prove that it works, I have used the old jar which was there when I have posted this answer)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20160810</version>
</dependency>
```

And the simple test code snippet will be:

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        JSONArray array = new JSONArray();

        JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
        object.put("key1", "value1");

        array.put(object);

        array.forEach(item -> {
            System.out.println(item.toString());
        });
    }
}
```

output:

```
{"key1":"value1"}
```

Comment: can achieve the same if using [retrolambda](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Retrolambda/article.html) with java 7

Comment: The method forEach((<no type> item) -> {}) is undefined for the type 
 JSONArray

Comment: @Jugi the json library that I have used above is `org.json` and you can use `forEach` on `JSONArray`, you can check once if you are still in doubt

Comment: I beg to differ with Jugi and akcasoy. This works for me with Java 8 and org.json.JSONArray.

Comment: This works with org.json here -> https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json Make sure you aren't using the wrong org.json

Comment: Also note that forEach() doesn't give you all the options a true Iterator will give. For more features, use the following: Iterator<?> arrayi = arrayJson.iterator(); while (arrayi.hasNext()) { JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) arrayi.next(); }

Answer (score 2):

- Inside the ***for*** loop, you can simply typecast `Object` to `JSONObject` and access the values.

Eg:

```
    JSONArray myJSONArray = [...Some JSONObjects Here...];

    for (Object myObject : myJSONArray) {

        //If you want to get JSONObject
        JSONObject myJSONObject = (JSONObject) myObject;

        //If you want to access JSONObject's values
        long number     = myJSONObject.getLong("myNum");
        String myString = myJSONObject.getString("myStr");
    }
```