# How to iterate through JSONArray which has JSONArray and JSONObject inside Java 8

Tags: arrays, json, java-8, jackson, objectmapper

Could anyone tell me how to iterate through `JSONArray` which returns both `JSONArray` and `JSONObject` in it.
I tried below code and I'm getting error as below.

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of 'com.example.jsonarr.pojoClass[]' out of START_OBJECT token
```

**Code**

```
List<pojoClass> pojoClassList = new ArrayList();
JSONArray jsonArrayList = new JSONArray( jsonResponse );
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper(  );
pojoClassList = (List)objectMapper.readValue(jsonArrayList.toString(),
                        objectMapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, pojoClass[].class));
```

**JSONArray**

```
[
  {
  "Key1": "Value1",
  "Key2": "Value2",
  "Key3": "Value3",
  "Value1_tim":       {
     "amVal": 0,
     "pmVal": "0"
    }
  },
  [   {
  "Key1": "Value1",
  "Key2": "Value2",
  "Key3": "Value3",
  "Value1_tim":       {
     "amVal": 0,
     "pmVal": "0"
  }
  }]
]
```

**With normal for loop.**

```
for ( int i = 0; i < jsonArrayList.length(); i++ ) {
     JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArrayList.optJSONObject( i );
     if ( jsonObject != null ) {
        pojoClass = objectMapper.readValue( jsonObject.toString(), PojoClass.class );
           }
     if ( jsonObject == null ) {
        JSONArray jsonArrayInner = new JSONArray( jsonArrayList.getJSONArray( i ).toString() );
        for ( int j = 0; j < jsonArrayInner.length(); j++ ) {
         JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArrayList.optJSONObject( j );
           if ( jsonObject1 != null ) {
            pojoClass = objectMapper.readValue( jsonObject1.toString(), PojoClass.class );
                 }
             }
         }
    pojoClassList.add( pojoClass );
  }
```

How do I do that with `Java 8`?

Comment: You can check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33215539/foreach-with-jsonarray-and-jsonobject/33215597

Answer (score 0):

If you use `Jackson`'s `ObjectMapper` try to use [`ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationFeature.html#ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY) feature which allows to treat single elements as `one-element-array`. Below, you can find simple example how to read your `JSON` to list of `Pojo` classes:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.CollectionType;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class JsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File jsonFile = new File("./resource/test.json").getAbsoluteFile();

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
        mapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
        mapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY);

        CollectionType collectionType0 = mapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, Pojo.class);
        CollectionType collectionType1 = mapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, collectionType0);
        List<List<Pojo>> list = mapper.readValue(jsonFile, collectionType1);

        List<Pojo> pojos = list.stream()
                .flatMap(List::stream)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(pojos);
    }
}

class Pojo {

    @JsonProperty("Key1")
    private String key1;

    // getters, setters, toString
}
```

Above code prints:

```
[Pojo{key1='Value1'}, Pojo{key1='Value1-1'}]
```

Comment: I'm still getting an error `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.String` out of START_ARRAY token`

Comment: It's failing in line `List<List<Pojo>> list = mapper.readValue(jsonFile, collectionType1);`

Comment: @Sam, I have tested it for `JSON` payload you included to a question. Have you tested it for the same `JSON`?

Comment: Yes, its the same payload. It's of type `JSONArray`. It's working fine when it returns `JSONObject`, however the second value is of `JSONArray`.

Comment: @Sam, which version of `Jackson` do you use? I've tested it for the latest one.

Comment: I'm using `2.9.4` version of `Jackson`.

Comment: @Sam, could run my example with yours `JSON` and check whether it works for you properly? I think that your `POJO` could be a problem.